# Program "head templates"

Tags: programming-languages

Can someone tell me what should I put in my program "head"?

Netbeans generate only this:

```
 /**
 *
 * @author Wolfy
 */
```

Do you have any good advice?

Comment: Follow the conventions of your team and programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I can't tell you what you should put in your program 'head', but I know a man who can: [Steve McConnell](http://cc2e.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You may put there a short description of your program, if you really want to put something, and if the conventions of your team (as Brian said in the comment) do not give you any guides.